# BCNF when no keys are available

Tags: normalization

I have a problem understanding a particular case of BCNF. 
Let's suppose that we have a relation R(B, C, D) with df:{C->D}.
Is my relation in BCNF and if yes why???
Is C considered as superkey?

Answer (score 4):

The only key is {BC}. You have a partial key dependency: C->D. Since you have a partial key dependency, R is not in 2NF. So R is also not in BCNF.

An informal way of expressing BCNF is that every arrow in every FD is an arrow that comes out of a candidate key. In R, the arrow in "C->D" doesn't come out of a candidate key.